# Relative pronoun THAT and its omission

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns, that

I recently encountered a grammar problem as follows:

> "I hope it'll rain tomorrow."
>
> "From ( ) you've just said, maybe you don't want to go on the picnic."
>
> i. that
>
> ii. what
>
> iii. where
>
> iv. which

Well, the answer is of course supposed to be (ii). However, one student thought it was (i). He gives this sentence:

> From that that you've just said...

He claims that the first "that" indicates the entire sentence starting "I hope ..." and the second one works as a relative pronoun here. Omitting the second one, he got

> From that you've just said...

What do you think about his claim? Both he and I know this sentence sounds unnatural, but at least from the grammatical viewpoint, we have no idea why it's not correct.

Comment: Sorry to point this out but there is no omission of that in ii). Only in the first.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why that would work here. I think what is a better choice.

Like, "From all that you've just said"

If you speak it aloud you that would work, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently nothing wrong grammatically with this combination but it must be rare. I could find but one example of "that (that)" preceded by "from" in which the second "that" is a relative.

([In the Senate of the United States, June 4, 1872...: Mr. ... - 1872](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/In_the_Senate_of_the_United_States_June/yqsUAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22from+that+you%22&pg=PA152&printsec=frontcover)) A . Yes , sir ; but that is a different statement from that you made before.

On the basis of the alternatives that a rather descriptive grammar considers usual "that that" does not occur. (*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, Quirk et al.)

> ***That which*** upsets me most is his manner.
> *or*
> ***What*** upsets me most is his manner.

- <s>***That that*** upsets me most is his manner.</s>

Moreover, "that which" is considered to be formal; it is rare and generally replaced by "what" (CoGEL).

You could use "that which", but it would sound formal.

- From that which you've just said...

Comment: I'd say CGEL's failing even to mention  'That upsets me [the] most' meaning 'What upsets me [the] most' is better claimed to indicate _unacceptability_ than a single example of a usage is to indicate acceptability. Note also that 'From { } you've just said' is a different construction from '[This] is a different statement from {that} you made before. In the latter, 'that' acceptably references a specific statement , whereas { } above needs a more general {what} (or a more robust nominal such as [from] {your recent diatribe/communication}.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had noticed that "from" didn't enter into the same syntactic combination; I noticed further that there was no equivalence between "that" and "what" but couldn't figure out the reason.